# PHP: How do I get an attribute from a JSON array?

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON array:

```
<?php    
$json = {
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "street_address" ],
    "formatted_address": "5721 N Northcott Ave, Chicago, IL 60631, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "5721",
      "short_name": "5721",
      "types": [ "street_number" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Illinois",
      "short_name": "IL",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "60631",
      "short_name": "60631",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 41.9858860,
        "lng": -87.7907460
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 41.9827384,
          "lng": -87.7938936
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 41.9890336,
          "lng": -87.7875984
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
};
?>
```

Using PHP, how do I get the `geometery->location->lat`&`lng` values from my JSON array above?

For example (pseudo code):

```
<?php
$lat = $json['geometry']['location']['lat'];  // 41.9858860
$lng = $json['geometry']['location']['lng'];  // -87.7907460
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) and then `$var->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;`.

`json_decode` yields the following structure:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'status' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  public 'results' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'types' => 
            array
              0 => string 'street_address' (length=14)
          public 'formatted_address' => string '5721 N Northcott Ave, Chicago, IL 60631, USA' (length=44)
          public 'address_components' => 
            array
              0 => 
                object(stdClass)[3]
                  public 'long_name' => string '5721' (length=4)
                  public 'short_name' => string '5721' (length=4)
                  public 'types' => 
                    array
                      0 => string 'street_number' (length=13)
              1 => 
                object(stdClass)[4]
                  public 'long_name' => string 'Illinois' (length=8)
                  public 'short_name' => string 'IL' (length=2)
                  public 'types' => 
                    array
                      0 => string 'administrative_area_level_1' (length=27)
                      1 => string 'political' (length=9)
              2 => 
                object(stdClass)[5]
                  public 'long_name' => string '60631' (length=5)
                  public 'short_name' => string '60631' (length=5)
                  public 'types' => 
                    array
                      0 => string 'postal_code' (length=11)
          public 'geometry' => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
              public 'location' => 
                object(stdClass)[7]
                  public 'lat' => float 41.985886
                  public 'lng' => float -87.790746
              public 'location_type' => string 'ROOFTOP' (length=7)
              public 'viewport' => 
                object(stdClass)[8]
                  public 'southwest' => 
                    object(stdClass)[9]
                      public 'lat' => float 41.9827384
                      public 'lng' => float -87.7938936
                  public 'northeast' => 
                    object(stdClass)[10]
                      public 'lat' => float 41.9890336
                      public 'lng' => float -87.7875984
```

Answer (score 3):

You use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

E.g.:

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json);
echo $json_obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
```

We access the first element of the results array, then navigate through the geometry, location, and lat properties.  You can also make it use associative arrays, but the default is an object.

Comment: If I use json_decode, then what? How would I reference the LAT and LNG values?

Comment: I've actually already read the examples in that link and still couldn't figure it out. Which is why I'm posting this question to SO now

Answer (score 2):

Greetings,

I recommend reading the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) documentation

```
  <?php 
     $obj = json_decode($json);
     $lat = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
  ?>
```

Comment: I've actually already read the examples in that link and still couldn't figure it out. Which is why I'm posting this question to SO now.

Comment: Righteo. Well I hope you got it sorted.